# Is it possible to publish multiple metrics at different stages of a Mono pipeline?

Tags: project-reactor, metrics

Is there a way to provide multiple duration metrics on a Mono? With the idea of getting more fine grained duration metrics for multiple stages. Consider the following example:

```
fetchSomeData()
  .flatMap { (data) -> processDataStage1(data)
     .name("processDataStage1")
     .metrics()
  }
  .flatMap { (data) -> processDataStage2(data)
     .name("processDataStage2")
     .metrics()
  }
  .name("total")
  .metrics()
```

We have a similar structure in our app, and the resulting metrics all report the same duration.

From the documentation of the "[name].flow.duration" metric it says:

> Times the duration elapsed between a subscription and the termination
> or cancellation of the sequence. A status tag is added to specify what
> event caused the timer to end (completed, completedEmpty, error,
> cancelled).

Which I believe explains this behavior; the full pipeline is subscribed once, hence the duration is the time until completed. Is there an operator that would allow us to split these to achieve multiple metrics? Ie. wrap on Defer, etc? thanks.